# i am trying to make a file upload but it is not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, xampp, lampp

I'm trying to make an easy image upload for my webchat application. I've switched from Windows to Linux (xampp to lampp) and now my fileupload script isn't working any more... I tried to change the directory owner with chown and also to change the read/write rights but nothing worked for me, so now I'm trying my best on stackoverflow.

My uploadfolder is here: /storage/www/messenger/data/profilepictures

and my script is here: /storage/www/messenger/functions/upload-img.php

here is my code

**change-image.html**

```
<form action="/messenger/functions/upload2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="datei"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Hochladen">
</form>
```

**upload-img.php**

```
<?php
$upload_folder = '/messenger/data/profilepictures/'; //Upload directory

$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


//checking of the file extention

$allowed_extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

if(!in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {

 die("Only png, jpg, jpeg and gif-files are allowed");

}

//checking the file size

$max_size = 52428800; //500 MB

if($_FILES['datei']['size'] > $max_size) {

 die("500MB is the max file size");

}

//checking if the file is ok

if(function_exists('exif_imagetype')) { //Die exif_imagetype-Funktion erfordert die exif-Erweiterung auf dem Server

 $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);

 $detected_type = exif_imagetype($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name']);

 if(!in_array($detected_type, $allowed_types)) {

 die("you are not allowed to upload other files than pictures");

 }

}

//path to upload

$new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'.'.$extension;

//Neuer Dateiname falls die Datei bereits existiert

if(file_exists($new_path)) { //Falls Datei existiert, hänge eine Zahl an den Dateinamen

 $id = 1;



do {



$new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'_'.$id.'.'.$extension;

 $id++;

 } while(file_exists($new_path));

}

//everything alright, move file to new pos.

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], $new_path);

echo 'Bild erfolgreich hochgeladen: <a href="'.$new_path.'">'.$new_path.'</a>';

?>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` superglobal.

Before:

`$upload_folder = '/messenger/data/profilepictures/';`

After:

`$upload_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/messenger/data/profilepictures/';`